# jquery how to get data-id value of datatable row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am working on `jquery datatable`. I am adding user input data into rows.

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
            
            name = $('#name').val();
            email = $('#email').val();
            cno = $('#cno').val();
            bdy = $('#bday').val();
            t.row.add([
                name,
                email,
                cno,
                bdy,
                '<button class ="btn btn-danger del">Delete</button>' + '' + '<button class="btn btn-warning upd" data-id="'+$('#example').DataTable().rows().count()+'">Edit</button>'
            ]).draw(false);
            $("#name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#cno").val('');
            $("#bday").val('');

        });
```

In the above code, there is `data-id` in which I am adding rows count. Now I am also deleting the row.

```
 $("body").on("click", ".del", function() {

            if ($(row).hasClass('child')) {
                t.row($(row).prev('tr')).remove().draw();
            } else {
                t.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            }
        });
```

After deleting the row. The row count is `n-1`. I want to get the latest `data-id` value whenever I try to add new row. For example I have added 3 rows and the row count is 3 so the `data-id` would be 3. So I want to get the last/latest value of `data-id`

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: you mean  you add row, so data-id +1, at once a delete row comes, the data-id is locked to its last value before del?  and even after if add row arrives data-id stays locked?

Comment: The value of `data-id` is `0` on the first run. Its value is `1` when the 2nd row is added, then `2` when the third row is added up to so on. But for example, when I delete the 2nd row having the `data-id = 1` and the last `data-id` value was `2`. Now  If i add a new row the data id should  be `2+1` i.e. the  last value of  `data-id` plus `1` so in that case there is no duplication in it

Comment: ok i undesratnd better, you dont want to reindex all data-id from 0? (it easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

i search the max data-id , so no problem of duplicate

as suggested by @FilipKováč, if you are sure the last row has always the max id, you could try:  `var max = parseInt($("button.upd").last().data("id") || 0);` instead of my line with map.. its better in performance

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
            var values = $.map($("button.upd"), function(el, index) { return parseInt($(el).attr("data-id")); });
            var max = Math.max.apply(null, values.length == 0 ? [0] : values);

            name = $('#name').val();
            email = $('#email').val();
            cno = $('#cno').val();
            bdy = $('#bday').val();
            t.row.add([
                name,
                email,
                cno,
                bdy,
                '<button class ="btn btn-danger del">Delete</button>' + '' + '<button class="btn btn-warning upd" data-id="'+ (max + 1) +'">Edit</button>'
            ]).draw(false);
            $("#name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#cno").val('');
            $("#bday").val('');

        });

 $("body").on("click", ".del", function() {
            if ($(row).hasClass('child')) {
                t.row($(row).prev('tr')).remove().draw();
            } else {
                t.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            }
        });
```

if you want to reindex data-id:

```
$("button.upd").each(function(index){
  $(this).attr("data-id", index);
}
```

you do that in delete function.. and you keep your initial code in your Add function

Comment: It doesn't works for me. the  row count was the same so the next added row had the  same `data-id` value as of the  last one

Comment: @Moeez, ok i calcul the max value of data-id, so no problem of duplicate

Comment: I have tried your code. But now I am getting `-Infinity` in `data-id` against 1st row

Comment: on the first row the array is empty for values, so i set 0 in case of, so the first row will be 1

Comment: why would you use `map` when you can use selector which finds the last row: `table > tbody > tr:last-child` and then find the id of its row cause the last row will have the max id every time. `max` would looks like `const max = parseInt($(row).find('btn.upd').data('id') || 0)++`

Comment: @FilipKováč you have right if the max id is always in  last row

Comment: @Frenchy what if I want to start first row from `0` rather  than `1`?

Comment: you just chnage [0] by [-1]  or || 0 by || -1

Comment: @Frenchy and what If I am using `var max = parseInt($("button.upd").last().data("id") || 0);` then how  to make sure that it  starts with `0` rather  than `1`

Comment: i have given you the respons in my last message  || - 1 or replace max + 1 by max.. i set -1 because max + 1 = 0... so

Comment: @Frenchy with replacing `|| 0` by  `|| -1` in `var max = parseInt($("button.upd").last().data("id") || -1);` the `data-id` is  always  `0`

Comment: sorry i dont see why, you have always zero, the code is basic..and this line of code is correct,  it trap the last button with class upd and trap the data-id value, if no button, max has the value after the or (||)..

Comment: @Frenchy your other approach is working, but this one is quite simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229527/discussion-between-frenchy-and-moeez).